# Convert each entry '(,)' list to without string

Tags: python, type-conversion

If you have a list in python lets say:

```py
list1 = ['(18,430)', '(19,430)', '(19,429)', '(19,428)', '(19,427)', '(18,426)',
         '(17,426)', '(17,425)', '(17,424)', '(17,423)', '(17,422)', '(17,421)',
         '(17,420)', '(17,421)']
```

and you want to convert each element of the list without string and create a new list lets say:

```
new_list = [(18,430), (19,430), (19,429), (19,428), (19,427), (18,426),
            (17,426), (17,425), (17,424), (17,423), (17,422), (17,421),
            (17,420), (17,421)]
```

How would you do this in python? Also would each of the individual values in
`new_list`, for example `(18,430)`, be considered a tuple?

Comment: I recommend trying out the answer first, then posting the code and then asking for help. I looked at 2 of your questions. Both of them do not have your attempts to solve. As you continue using Stack Overflow, please plan to provide your code along with the questions.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do that for your example would be to use the builtin [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
new_list = [eval(item) for item in list1]
```

If the strings are more complex it would be better to use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html) module:

```
from ast import literal_eval

new_list = [literal_eval(item) for item in list1]
```

And yes, each element of `new_list` would be a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, str to tuple conversion will only generate a new tuple with all string chars on it, so you can't make the explicit conversion, either you will need to create a function to convert from a string to a tuple, or slice the parentheses from it, convert it into a number and then create a tuple with that number, later you create a new list and insert the newly created tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this a few hours ago. Here's how to do this.

Assumption: All items in list1 are tuples of integers stored as strings.

```
list1 = ['(18,430)', '(19,430)', '(19,429)',
         '(19,428)', '(19,427)', '(18,426)',
         '(17,426)', '(17,425)', '(17,424)',
         '(17,423)', '(17,422)', '(17,421)',
         '(17,420)', '(17,421)' ]

list2 = [tuple(map(int,(i.replace(')','').replace('(','')).split(','))) for i in list1]
print (list2)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[(18, 430), (19, 430), (19, 429), 
 (19, 428), (19, 427), (18, 426), 
 (17, 426), (17, 425), (17, 424), 
 (17, 423), (17, 422), (17, 421), 
 (17, 420), (17, 421)]
```